# Why can't I use order in find method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In script/console

```
Storage.find(:all , :conditions => "item_id=1" , order => "expire_date DESC")
```

I get

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `order' for #<Object:0xb7761954>
    from (irb):5
```

But it works when I use

```
Storage.find(:all , :conditions => "item_id=1")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`order` should be a symbol, `:order => "expire_date DESC"`

Comment: no problem. i have spent hours debugging and searching google for solutions to problems which came down to something as simple as this before. I think everyone has, so don't feel bad :)